# Flutter + MySQL: Mutltiple queries in a row not working (1 insert + 2 update)

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I have a form with some data that is pushed to a database upon pressing a button. The data is sports score data, and in the end, I want to count only the top 10 scores for each player. Besides the values that I insert (`id`, `course`, `date`, `score`) the table also holds a column `NotActive` that is `1` f the score is among the top 10 for the player and should be counted, and 0 if it isn't.

To do this I use [myqsl1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1) and have created three queries to run upon clicking the submit button (granted that the form completes the validation). I have one query for inserting data, a second query for setting all `NotActive` to `1` for that player, and a third query where I want to set `NotActive` to `0` for the top 10 highest scores from that player (see code below).

```
void insertScore(id, date, course, score) async {
    dynamic conn = await connect();

    String query1 =
        "insert into Score (Bandit_ID, Bane, dato, Scores) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    await conn.query(query1, [id, course, date, score]);

    conn.close();
  }

  void updateDbActive1(id) async {
    dynamic conn = await connect();

    String query = "UPDATE Score SET IkkeAktiv = 1 WHERE Bandit_ID = ?";

    await conn.query(query, [id]);

    conn.close();
  }

  void updateDbActive2(id) async {
    dynamic conn = await connect();

    String query =
        "UPDATE Score SET IkkeAktiv = 0 WHERE Bandit_ID = ? ORDER BY Scores DESC LIMIT 10";

    await conn.query(query, [id]);

    conn.close();
  }
```

When running the queries inside phpMyAdmin the queries all output the expected result. But when I execute all three queries on the buttonpress this happens:

1. `insertScore()` runs as expected and inputs the values with `NotActive` defaulting to `1`.
2. `updateDbActive1()` runs and is able to set every `NotActive = 1` for the given player. (Though, if I change it to set every `NotActive = 0` instead, it will update all except the most recently added one.)
3. `updateDbActive2()` doesn't update anything at all.

The queries are called consecutively after the button's `onPressed` and a form validation:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        _formKey.currentState!.save();

        id = nameController.text;
        date = dateController.text;
        course = courseController.text;
        score = scoreController.text;

        setState(() {
            nameController.text = "";
            dateController.text = "";
            courseController.text = "";
            scoreController.text = "";
        });

        database.insertScore(id, date, course, score);
        database.updateDbActive1(id);
        database.updateDbActive2(id);

        shouldDisplay = !shouldDisplay;
    }
    
    shouldDisplay ? showAlertDialog(...)
...
```

Have I missed something about making multiple queries that should invalidate my setup? The queries should be good - but if you have a better way to make the two updates I will appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to fix it. I added delay to both update functions, and it works as intended. Below is the updated code. If anyone can explain why this works and my first attempt doesn't, I would appreciate it. If you have a better solution, please don't hesitate to bring it forward.

```
void insertScore(id, date, course, score) async {
    dynamic conn = await connect();

    String query1 =
        "insert into Score (Bandit_ID, Bane, dato, Scores) values (?, ?, ?,?)";

    await conn.query(query1, [id, course, date, score]);

    conn.close();
  }

Future<void> updateDbActive1(id) async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
      dynamic conn = await connect();

      String query = "UPDATE Score SET IkkeAktiv = 1 WHERE Bandit_ID = ?";

      await conn.query(query, [id]);

      conn.close();
    });
  }

Future<void> updateDbActive2(id) async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
      dynamic conn = await connect();

      String query =
          "UPDATE Score SET IkkeAktiv = 0 WHERE Bandit_ID = ? ORDER BY Scores DESC LIMIT 10";

      await conn.query(query, [id]);

      conn.close();
    });
  }
}
```